# Xpath запрос в VBA

Tags: vba

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно написать макрос на VBA, который откроет XML файл через FileDialog, запустит Юзерформу, где пользователь выберет элемент, содержание которого будет записано в XLS файл.
С Юзерформой и открытием файла я вроде разобрался.
Но у меня возникли проблемы с XPATH запросом.
Код:

```
Sub subReadXMLStream()
Dim dlg As FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
If dlg.Show Then
Open dlg.SelectedItems(1) For Random As #1
End If 
UserForm1.Show
```

Часть кода Юзерформы:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Dim Loc As String
Set XMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set Loc = XMLFile.getElementsByTagName("loc")
End Sub
```

В коде Юзерформы явно есть какая-то ошибка, ибо я получаю это:
"Object Required"
И ругается оно на эту часть кода: `XMLFile.getElementsByTagName("loc")`
Не подскажите, как это исправить?
И правильно ли я открываю XML файл? Спасибо.

Comment: Присваивание вида `Set var_name = object` используется для объектных переменные, так как у Вас `Loc` строковая переменная, то попробуйте из строки присваивания убрать ключевое слово `Set`

Comment: Вот так надо открывать https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff838643.aspx